# SQL Server : Group by select statment give error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

- `PersonTBL` table : includes the column `HostAddress` which stores the IP address of Person
- `ip-to-country` table: include the range of IP numbers with countries

I am trying to count the persons per country, but I received an error:

> Invalid column name 'CountryName'.

Query:

```
SELECT  
    Count(HostAddress) as TotalNo,
    (select [ip-to-country].CountryName 
     from [ip-to-country] 
     where ((CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 4) AS Bigint) * 256 * 256 * 256) + 
            (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 3) AS INT) * 256 * 256) + 
            (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 2) AS INT) * 256) + 
             CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 1) AS INT))
            BETWEEN [ip-to-country].BegingIP AND [ip-to-country].EndIP) AS CountryName
FROM PersonTBL 
GROUP BY
   CountryName
```

I also tried :

```
SELECT  
    Count(HostAddress) as TotalNo,
    (SELECT [ip-to-country].CountryName 
     FROM [ip-to-country] 
     WHERE 
        ((CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 4) AS Bigint) * 256 * 256 * 256) + 
         (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 3) AS INT) * 256 * 256) +
         (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 2) AS INT) * 256) +
         CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 1) AS INT)) BETWEEN [ip-to-country].BegingIP AND [ip-to-country].EndIP) as CountryName
FROM PersonTBL 
GROUP BY 
    (SELECT [ip-to-country].CountryName 
     FROM [ip-to-country] 
     WHERE 
        ((CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 4) AS Bigint) * 256 * 256 * 256) + 
         (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 3) AS INT) * 256 * 256) +
         (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 2) AS INT) * 256) +
         CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 1) AS INT)) BETWEEN [ip-to-country].BegingIP AND [ip-to-country].EndIP) as CountryName
```

But I received another error :

> Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Can any one help me to group the users by country ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a column alias directly on the `GROUP BY` if you just define that alias, you either use the same expression on the `GROUP BY` or use a derived table or a CTE:

Derived Table:

```
SELECT  COUNT(HostAddress) AS TotalNo, 
        CountryName
FROM (  SELECT  HostAddress,
                (SELECT [ip-to-country].CountryName 
                 FROM [ip-to-country] 
                 WHERE 
                 ((CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 4) AS BIGINT)*256*256*256) + 
                 (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 3) AS INT)*256*256)
                  + (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 2) AS INT)*256) 
                  + CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 1) AS INT))
                 BETWEEN  [ip-to-country].BegingIP and [ip-to-country].EndIP) AS CountryName
         FROM PersonTBL) T
 GROUP BY CountryName
```

CTE (SQL Server 2005+):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  HostAddress,
            (SELECT [ip-to-country].CountryName 
             FROM [ip-to-country] 
             WHERE 
             ((CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 4) AS BIGINT)*256*256*256) + 
             (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 3) AS INT)*256*256)
              + (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 2) AS INT)*256) 
              + CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 1) AS INT))
             BETWEEN  [ip-to-country].BegingIP and [ip-to-country].EndIP) AS CountryName
     FROM PersonTBL
)
SELECT  COUNT(HostAddress) AS TotalNo, 
        CountryName
FROM CTE
GROUP BY CountryName
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can't use column aliases in the `group by` clause.  Here is an alternative:

```
with cte as (
     SELECT HostAddress,
            (select [ip-to-country].CountryName
             from [ip-to-country]
             where ((CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 4) AS Bigint)*256*256*256) + 
                    (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 3) AS INT)*256*256) +
                    (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 2) AS INT)*256) +
                     CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 1) AS INT)
                   ) between  [ip-to-country].BegingIP and [ip-to-country].EndIP
            ) as CountryName
     FROM PersonTBL
    )
select count(HostAddress) as TotalNo, CountryName
from cte
Group By CountryName;
```

Answer (score -3):

You're missing a ). Try:

```
SELECT  Count(HostAddress) as TotalNo,
 (select [ip-to-country].CountryName from [ip-to-country] where 
 ((CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 4) AS Bigint)*256*256*256) + 
(CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 3) AS INT)*256*256)
 + (CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 2) AS INT)*256) 
 + CAST(PARSENAME(HostAddress, 1) AS INT))
between  [ip-to-country].BegingIP and [ip-to-country].EndIP) as CountryName
)
 FROM PersonTBL 
 Group By 
 CountryName
```

I haven't got your table so I'm not sure it'll work, but it's more likely to!

Comment: This won't work, you can't use the column alias like that on the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Put the inserted ) before the 'as Country' just before it.